# Are standard C# class objects created in a WCF service multiplatform?

Tags: c#, wcf, multiplatform

I've written a WCF Service that is used to retrieve and update my database when requests are made from the client programs. Currently it only serves UWP apps and a WinForms desktop client, so I have used standard c# class objects for moving data around.

If I wanted to expand to also include non .NET applications(eg. android, ios, java etc), would these classes be usable by those platforms (when used with a service reference), or would I need to move to something else - such as JSON?

Comment: For android or IOS better to move JSON

Comment: @Vinoth are there any advantages to using JSON over other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android or IOS better to move JSON

Some advantages of using JSON  [Click](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2008/12/27/performance-comparison-soap-vs-json-wcf-implementation.aspx)

Comment: After looking into it, JSON certainly looks like a strong candidate

Answer (score 0):

According to what I've found, it should be possible to use our WCF service multiplatform. However it seems like that it still needs some changes and or using some additional frameworks.
Look into this:
[Walkthrough - Working with WCF](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/)

This ends up using Xamarin with [web service stuff](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/).
At least, Xamarin can be used with [Visual Studio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/visual-studio/)

Comment: sadly xamarin doesn't come cheap if you want VS integration, so i'm looking for other ways to implement cross platform compatible methods

Comment: Just mention that in your question :P :D . I'll have a look again

Comment: Revision to my previous comment. I hadn't realised that microsoft had purchased xamarin and include it as part of visual studio as standard now.

Comment: So is that fine now?

Comment: its an option that will be considered